# Why doesn't the offline cloud firestore documentation have code for offline query indexes for flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

[Documentation I'm referring to](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_query_indexes)

For other languages, I see it uses `persistentCacheIndexManager` and `enableIndexAutoCreation`. I tried to search in all files for some combinations of substrings of these words but I didn't find anything.

Is this feature still missing for Flutter? Does anyone know if there are any discussions about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `persistentCacheIndexManager` and `enableIndexAutoCreation` are relatively new features that were added to the Firestore SDK in [version 24.8.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#firestore_v24-8-0) on September 14, 2023.

> Is this feature still missing for Flutter?

Yes, these features aren't present in the [FirebaseFirestore](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore-class.html) class for Flutter because there wasn't an update yet. However, it's a matter of time until these two features will also be added.

Comment: Salut Claudiu. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Buna :) I didn't notice you were romanian. This is offtopic but I'm honored to have an answer from you. I'm also really greatful you wrote this article https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e

Comment: @ClaudiuRazlet Good to hear that, Claudiu :)